# XML schema primary key

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, primary-key

I'm trying to create XML database for employees and I have problem with the schema.

For each employee, I have four elements: name, surname, ID and email. How can I set ID as primary key and email as unique?

I tried this for primary key:

```
<xs:key msdata:PrimaryKey="true" type="xs:string" name="ID"/>
```

but it's not working. 
This is all my XML code:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="employees">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="employee">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>        
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Name"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Surname"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ID"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="e-mail"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
     <xs:key name="empl-key">
        <xs:selector xpath="employee"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@ID"/>
     </xs:key>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that's _all_ the schema?  The XML you've pasted is not well-formed (at the very least you're missing a quote after `elementFormDefault="qualified`), and it seems odd to have `elementFormDefault` in a schema with no `targetNamespace`.

Comment: I'm orry, the quote after elementFormDefault="qualified its missing because of a fault when I pasted it here. It's right on my code. 
I'm new in XML, so I use things that I don't understand exactly their meaning.

Comment: Also, your current schema requires _exactly one_ `employee` element in the `employees`, you need to add minOccurs and/or maxOccurs to allow more (or fewer) than one.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that if you want every Employee in a Company to have a unique ID, then you create an xs:key definition at the level of the Company element, in which the xs:selector path selects the Employee node from the Company element, and the xs:field path selects the ID node from the Employee node. Something like

```
<xs:element name="Company">
  ....
  <xs:key name="empl-key">
    <xs:selector xpath="Employee"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@ID"/>
  </xs:key>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately, it seems that it's not working.
Also, I tried to do it like this: 
<xs:key name="empl-key" msdata:PrimaryKey="true">
      <xs:selector xpath="employee"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@ID"/>
</xs:key>
But nothing happens.

Comment: Well, you did it wrong then. Perhaps you defined you key in the wrong place, or got the paths wrong. Perhaps there's a namespace involved. Impossible to debug from such a scanty code snippet.

Comment: I will edit my question and insert there my xml code.

Comment: Your ID is a child element, not an attribute, so remove the "@" sign in the field definition.